# I want to throw an exception when my mysql stored procedure doesn't find any results

Tags: mysql, exception, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm having trouble finding a way to throw an exception from a stored procedure if no data is found.

I need a way to check the query results in the if statement.

If the count is 0 then throw exception.  If there's data then return the data.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`adminHC`@`%` PROCEDURE `find_user_with_credentials`(
    IN `usernameIN` VARCHAR(45)
    , IN `encryptedpwIN` VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT distinct
            userid
            ,firstname
            ,lastname
            ,publicname
            ,email
            ,addressid
            ,create_date
            ,update_date
            ,active
        FROM dev_users
        WHERE (email = usernameIN OR (
                publicname IS NOT null AND
                publicname = usernameIN
            ))
            AND encryptedpw = encryptedpwIN
            AND active = 1) user;

    IF count(user) > 0 THEN
        SELECT user;
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Invalid username or password",
        MYSQL_ERRNO = 403;  
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: What is `@user`?

Comment: That's me not knowing what I"m doing.  I want @user to refer to the results from the query that is called user.

Comment: A variable can only hold a single value, not a whole table of results.

Comment: good practice for encrypted passwords is having random salt as part of them.  that means you can read the encrypted password, and use it to encrypt the entered plaintext password and see if they match, but you can't do what you seem to have here, encrypting a plaintext password and then seeing if it matches what's in the database.

Comment: I'm using a salt on the server.  The password entered by the user gets encrypted and checked against the encrypted password saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query and check the result of that.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`adminHC`@`%` PROCEDURE `find_user_with_credentials`(
    IN `usernameIN` VARCHAR(45)
    , IN `encryptedpwIN` VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dev_users
        WHERE (email = usernameIN OR (
                publicname IS NOT null AND
                publicname = usernameIN
            ))
            AND encryptedpw = encryptedpwIN
            AND active = 1) > 0
    THEN SELECT
            userid
            ,firstname
            ,lastname
            ,publicname
            ,email
            ,addressid
            ,create_date
            ,update_date
            ,active
        FROM dev_users
        WHERE (email = usernameIN OR (
                publicname IS NOT null AND
                publicname = usernameIN
            ))
            AND encryptedpw = encryptedpwIN
            AND active = 1;
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Invalid username or password",
        MYSQL_ERRNO = 403;  
    END IF;
END
```

There's also no need for the `SELECT *` wrapper. And I doubt you need `SELECT DISTINCT`, since I assume you can't have multiple rows with the same `userid`, and there's nothing in the query that will duplicate rows.

If the query were too expensive to do twice, you could do it once and save the results in a temporary table. Then you can use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table` to check if there are any results, and finally `SELECT * FROM temp_table` to return the data.

Comment: I love that.  Putting the whole thing in the if statement makes so much more sense.

I was trying for the temporary table approach but I couldn't figure it out.  I was trying to avoid running the query twice.

I'll try that out.  Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: I works perfectly.  Thanks again.

Ended up making a temp table and checking against that count in the subsequent if statement.